# Find letter in a string

Tags: python

I want to find the index of last instance of a letter in a string. The code should take a string and a character. For example, if I write `("hello", "l")`, I should get 3. Instead, i get -4. I know that 3 and -4 is the same depending on where you start to count, but I want to get 3. Here is my attempt:

```
def find(string, ch):
    index = 0
    while index < len(string):
        if string[index] == ch:
            return index
        index = index - 1
    return -1
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think  you mean the last index of a character in a string?

Answer (score 6):

Use the standard `rindex` method:

```
def find(s, ch):
    return s.rindex(ch)
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your code is wrong. Try this:

```
index = len(string) - 1
while index > 0:
    if string[index] == ch:
        return index
    index -= 1
return -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This worked!

Comment: @Newbie_01 Kindly accept the answer if it has helped you. It will help others who see this question later

Answer (score 1):

You're re-inventing the wheel.

```
my_string.rfind(char_or_substring)
```

Also, don't name your variable `string`. You're shadowing the python module with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(string, ch):
    index = -1
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == ch: index = i
    return index
```

Just look through string. When you find a character, then update the index value.